# RESTful API design for cross-table summary statistics

Tags: django, api, rest

Let's say I am creating a RESTful API for an online bookstore.

I have resources `authors`, `books` and `transactions`.

I'd like the API to return a list of:

- the most popular authors on a day (in terms of the number of transactions)
- the most popular books on a day (in terms of the number of transactions)

Is it possible to define a single URL endpoint for this purpose that is also flexible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
/api/v1/bookstore/popular/?filter=author&metric=transaction
/api/v1/bookstore/popular/?filter=book&metric=transaction
```